# Unable to load Firefox Addons website on Firefox!

Tags: 12.04, firefox, downloads

This is strange but since I have updated to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from 11.10, some websites simply refuse to open in Firefox browser. I have not been able to install any addon since the [site itself](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) does not load. Another important site i am unable to open is Wordpress.org.

I have tried opening them in Chromium and they are working just fine(So the network settings are fine, I guess). The problem seems to be limited to Firefox only and I want to resolve this issue than moving to another browser. Firefox is the only browser I intend to use.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your browser and settings by removing you `~/.mozilla` folder (move it to somewhere else just in case you actually need it), there might be something preventing you from opening some pages, if you want to restore the setting just move the folder back in to its original place.

You can see the `.mozilla` folder by opening Nautilus in your home and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>, after locating it just rename it to `.mozilla.old` with Firefox closed and re-open Firefox when done.

Has an option you can also open Firefox in safe mode by going to *Help* > *Restart with Add-ons Disabled* or by opening a terminal and typing `firefox -safe-mode`.

Comment: Before renaming or removing `~/.mozilla`, it might be worthwhile to  log in as `guest` and try running Firefox. This would use a different profile and thus would show whether or not the problem is user-specific.

Comment: Yeah, that also, it should have the same effect -load a fresh config- always forget about the lesser user since I don't really use it :/ Thx for the heads up.